# Do wheel types affect driving?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have to complete a number of off-road races, so first thing I did was drive to the nearest [Los Santos Customs](http://gta.wikia.com/Los_Santos_Customs).  While there, I decided to buy myself some shiny, new off-road wheels.
[image]
<sub>(source: [d4premiere.com](http://d4premiere.com/wp-content/upLoads/2013/07/Car-Customised-Custom-Wheels-GTA-V-GTA-5.jpg))</sub>

I noticed changing wheel types has no effect on the car attributes (*in particular, Traction*).  Does this mean wheel type has absolutely no effect on how the car performs? Or are there any hidden advantages to using different wheel types, *i.e. more/less wheel-slip*?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you going to compete in *single player* offroad races? If yes, you shouldn't take your own car. At the beginning of the offroad races you'll be seated in a predefined vehicle and might lose whichever vehicle you drove in to get there. The only races where you can use your own car are street races.

Comment: Additionally, *wheel types* are purely cosmetic. If you want to see gameplay changes involving wheels, you might want to look at the *wheel accessory* option. The only practical accessory you can get there, however, are *bulletproof wheels*.

Comment: @Nolonar thank you for the advice! I am primarily concerned though about whether or not using off-road wheels in an off-road race provides some sort of advantage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Original Answer**

You're not effecting the tire choice of the car, just the wheel rim.

I've tried many different wheel and surface combinations in a number of vehicles and haven't noticed any difference in terms of the cars handling.

Someone may be able to disprove me with numbers or something more empirical, as my evidence is purely anecdotal, but aside from the bulletproof tires, I believe all of the wheel mods are purely cosmetic.

**EDIT**: I've revisited my answer below.

**Updated Answer**

Some people with more time and patience than myself have taken the time to run a few tests and document everything.

Like this [reddit thread](http://np.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV/comments/1pw9sa/gtao_los_santos_customs_upgrade_tests/) where the poster records his times using the same vehicle with various upgrades on the same track surface, including stock car with each wheel type. This particular set of numbers reflects an extremely negligible difference between the wheel types.

There is also a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whvwdze4EFI) showing a slight difference in traction for the Off Road tires.

There is also this [reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/gtavcustoms/comments/1ny57i/tire_type_testing_and_analysis/) where the poster comes to the conclusion that the difference is somewhat negligible.

So, there is a lot of anecdotal evidence and some video, but I don't think anyone has found any confirmation in the code that wheel type has any modifier effects for a vehicle.

In summation, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Tire will change as well when you change rims.

Answer (score 0):

Wheel type is not purely cosmetic. Some people believe it is just because they don't see a stat change. I can tell you from personal experience what a few of the wheel types do.

Off-Road, as the name says, affects your cars ability to drive off-road. It improves the grip to the ground when going over terrain.

Tuner affects grip to the road. It makes the car stick very well which is good for recovering from spin-outs, it also makes going around turns less drifty. This also seems to affect acceleration (I'm not positive though), because whenever I use tuner wheels the car feels a bit faster than normal.

Muscle affects drift. It allows you to go around turns in a slide while maintaining control and speed much easier in the vehicle.

Sport, as far as I can tell, is a very standard wheel type, pretty much the balanced type.

That's all the ones I know, still haven't tested them all thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I am a strict off road dude. I've put off road tires on every vehicle Icould to test differences. I even put them on sportsters for when things get crazy and I end up in the woods. The tires grip the dirt much better. Its so noticeable that the only reason someone wouldn't notice is if they think they're strictly cosmetic before trying and some sort of placebo takes over. It was the same all the way back in SA. I did extensive testing for years with that game and its no different in gta v. As for rock crawling they don't seem to make to big of difference. Also, using dirt tires on street makes your acceleration noticeable worse. Gta v is so detailed and nothing is there by mistake. Quite frankly the thought of 7 different tire options being there for no reason other than looks is somewhat of a stupid conclusion. As for the other tire types, the previous poster seems spot on. In conclusion: the tires work like everything else in this game; they behave exactly like they look. I wish the "answered" post to this wasn't an incorrect paragraph in general that didn't answer the original posts question.

Answer (score 0):

So I came here after driving around in the new Imponte Nightshade for a bit.
I noticed the post about how each type seems to effect how it holds to the road, so I ran a few quick tests.
From a brief time with High end, Muscle and Tuner I can say I notice a slight difference, I already know off-road seems to have slightly better off road traction as many have seemed to prove (if only just).

High end seems to stick better in a straight line, provides slightly better traction but only just, the same applies with off-road but the difference between these two seem only to be when off the tarmac.

Tuner seems to stick better when turning, would probably be more noticeable on something like the elegy whilst tearing up around the shipping dock.
Sports and SUV seem to show little difference to each-other so no point bothering here.

Muscle, I'm happy about this, I slapped these on and went for the final quick spin and yeah... they do seem drift a bit more, good news for anybody like me looking for a bit more "fun".
Hope this helps anybody who appears here, sorry if I rant a bit, if anybody can go into more detail or argue this go ahead

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed a noticeable difference using off road tires on the panto.

I've used quite a few others, and on most cars i can't tell the difference, and only off road tires seem to change how the panto drives off road.